ADB Screencap save location
So currently I have an Android emulator running on my system. I then have a tool that runs adb commands to the emulator to cause certain screens to come up. My goal is to take screen shots of the emulator using screencap so then I can save the images to review later.
When using screencap I can't refer the path to anywhere in my C directory, as it errors out with
"Error opening file: C:Users/test.png (Read-only file system)"
I tried to use this command to use screencap. But then encountered the error message above
adb -s emulator-5554 shell screencap -p C:Users/test.png
I've also tried screencaping to /sdcard/test.png but I can't seem to find the file on my system.
If anyone can help that'd be greatly appreciated!

"But then encountered the error message above" -- I believe that the parameter to screencap refers to a filesystem path on the device or emulator. "I can't seem to find the file on my system" -- if by "my system" you mean your Windows machine, it will not be there. It will be in the filesystem of your emulator. You could use adb pull to copy it to your Windows machine.

You cannot save to a location on your C drive directly
You can save to a location on your internal storage of the emulator. Usually these locations have the following paths /storage/0/emulated/Downloads for Downloads
After that, you can do an adb pull operation
adb pull <location-on-emulator> <location-on-C-drive>

If you use this often, you can turn it into a shell script method and use it

Ah that makes sense. Thank you for helping!

You can mark the answer as accepted so that it helps other people

You can do it in a single command
adb shell screencap -p > myscreenshot.png

